# Invoke function in new thread powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can i create new thread and running in async? i have an event which should update text box in run time so i need to run it in different thread.
(powershell 2).
How can i do it in PowerShell?

Comment: As if you provide a little code sample I could add some sample code to my answer.

Comment: You could also do this with Powershell events , which run a action when the event occurs. This just means you dont need to worry about other threads/jobs etc

Answer (score 3):

Background Jobs are what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288(VS.85).aspx

Here's a few examples from help:

Starting a job with Start-Job:

```
C:\PS>start-job -scriptblock {get-process}

Id    Name  State    HasMoreData  Location   Command
---   ----  -----    -----------  --------   -------
1     Job1  Running  True         localhost  get-process
```

Starting a job with the AsJob parameter:

```
C:\PS>$jobWRM = invoke-command -computerName (get-content servers.txt) -scriptblock {get-service winrm} -jobname WinRM -throttlelimit 16 -AsJob
```